# How to import an SQL file by using mysqldump on Windows through command line

Tags: mysql

How do I import an SQL file to MySQL dump using command line.  I am using windows.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Navigate to the directory where you have mysql and issue this command, changing the bold values to your file/database locations.

```
c:\mysql\bin\> mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD database_name < filename.sql
```

Comment: I'm not sure about Windows, but under *nix, there shouldn't be any space between `-p` and the password.

Comment: with windows -p password loads the my.inf file. removing the space works.

Comment: this works fine with windows mysql -u USERNAME -p database_name < filename.sql. After this command you may have to enter your password.

Answer (score 1):

Simple steps to import sql file.

Click on WampServer and then go to MySQL=> MySQL console
enter password  \If no password click simply enter
create database database_name;   \If database already there skip this step
use database_name; 
source D:\backup.sql  \Path of database file

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

I think you need to use the full path at the command line, something like this, perhaps:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u {username} -p {databasename} < file_name.sql
```

Refer this link also:

http://www.ryantetek.com/2011/09/importing-large-sql-files-through-command-line-when-using-phpmyadminxampp/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
C:\Program Files\Mysql\Mysql server 5.6\bin\mysql -u {username} -p {password} {your database name} < file-name.sql
```

Note here file-name.sql is in mysql server 5.6\bin

Answer (score -1):

To dump all databases, use the `-all-databases` option.  With that option, no database needs to be specified.

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword –all-databases > dump.sql
```

Comment: This is to EXPORT, not to IMPORT.