# import MySQL DB from java not working

Tags: java, sql, runtime-error, mysql

I use this code to import (restore) .sql file:

```
String command2="/Users/macbookpro/mysql-5.6.16-osx10.7-x86_64/bin/mysql --host     mydb.ckwwsnbi2lvi.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port 3306 -u XXX -pXXXX testcomm </Users/macbookpro/Downloads/world3.sql"

Process runtimeProcess;
try {
    runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command2);
    processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

    if (processComplete == 0) {
        System.out.println("Backup restored successfully");
        // return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Could not restore the backup");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The command is working well in the terminal, but it's not working when I run Java code.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: any errors? stack trace? command line output? what does not work

Comment: The output "Could not restore the backup"

Comment: The database is imported when I used the command line  but nothing happen when I'm running this java code.

Comment: Please ensure that the users that runs the JVM has enough rights to run the exec() command. You can also try to read the runtimeProcess.getErrorStream() to check for any errors output from your process

Comment: I'm trying to export .sql file, and it's working well. The problem is only with importing.

Comment: I'll repeat - you should try to read your process error stream for errors. It is clear that the process was executed, but terminated with an error code.

Comment: I just get this warning "Error:  Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure." I don't think that is the problem because I got the same thing for exporting.

Comment: It does show that it is an error. One more thing is you want to send the output to a file: </Users/macbookpro/Downloads/world3.sql and I'm not quite if this would work using a java command - try removing this part and use the process input stream to get the file output and write it to a file manually

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping. The problem is solved. 
I'm replacing the string with String array and using '-e source' instead of '<'.

This is the new command:

```
    String[] command2 = new String[]{"/Users/macbookpro/mysql-5.6.16-osx10.7-x86_64/bin/mysql","--host=" + ad,"--port=" + pt,"--user=" + u,"--password="+ p,"testcomm","-e"," source "+"/Users/macbookpro/Downloads/world3.sql"};
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093958/how-to-restore-a-mysql-database-backup-using-java) is helpful for me.

Comment: would u mind share the complete code because now you're using array instead of normal String.