# Runtime process to restore mySQL database

Tags: java, mysql

Similar to this link: "[How to restore a MySQL database backup using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093958/how-to-restore-a-mysql-database-backup-using-java)"

I'm trying to restore a database using mysql.exe by executing the command through runtime processes. I've tried several commands but I can't seem to make it work. They all seem to hang and return an exit value of 1.

These are the commands I've tried:

```
    String executeCmd = mySQLDir+"\\bin\\mysql -u root --password= testdb < " + backupFile;
    String[] executeCmd = new String[]{mySQLDir+"\\bin\\mysql", "-u", "root", "--password=", "testdb", " < " + backupFile};
    String[] executeCmd = new String[]{mySQLDir+"\\bin\\mysql", "--user=root", "--password=" , "testdb -e", " source "+backupFile};  
    String executeCmd = mySQLDir+"\\bin\\mysql -u root --password= testdb -e source "+ backupFile;
```

I've tried to output what trying to happen during the execution through input stream and this occurs prints out (There's a lot more text but the first two lines are this):

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.9-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Usage: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
```

So from what I'm understanding it doesn't seem to recognize the commands through java, but doing it through command prompt seems to work. Any ideas?

Edit: A user mentioned that command might be incorrect so heres the output to the third executeCommand:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql
--user=root
--password=
testdb -e
source C:\Users\AA\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestProject\backup\testDBBackup69-03-2016%19-27-45.sql
```

I tried playing around with spaces in second command :

```
String[] executeCmd = new String[]{mySQLDir+"\\bin\\mysql", " -u ", "root", " --password=", " testdb ", "< " + backupFile};
```

result in using system.print output:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root --password= test < C:\Users\AA\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestProject\backup\testDBBackup69-03-2016%19-27-45.sql
```

I know this command works for sure in cmd but still doesn't work in java

I have solved the issue, answer is below.

Comment: _"it doesn't seem to recognize the commands"_ -- actually, the command executed, but the options you provided were incorrect.  You need to print out the commands before you execute them so you can see what is being sent to the command on the command line.

Comment: I've updated the OP, I still can't for the life of me understand why it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue by using Process Builder class instead.

Example code:

```
        String[] command = new String[]{mySQLDir+"\\bin\\mysql ", "-uroot", "--password=", "testdb"};
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(command));
        processBuilder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
        processBuilder.redirectInput(Redirect.from(backupFile));
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get redirection unless you start a shell. An exe won't understand `<`.

Put `"cmd", "/c"` into the front of the String[] array.

Comment: You mean like this 

String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"cmd","/c",mySQLDir+"\\bin\\mysql", "-u", "root", "--password=", "testdb", "< "+backupFile};

If so I still get same issue

Comment: The `<` needs to be in an argument of its own.