# How to restore a mysql dump file using java jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Is there any way to restore a .sql which is a backup of a database into a newly created database using java jdbc?

"mysql -u root -password stdtravels1 <  C:/Users/j/Desktop/std.sql"

I already tried the above code. still with no sucess

Comment: mysql is the command. not query

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysql -u username -password dbName  xxx.sql")
```

Using this you could restore.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start mysqldump -u root -password stdtravels1 <  C:/Users/j/Desktop/std.sql");  this is how I did it? but does not work.... anything wrong in here?

Comment: Try to look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755552/how-to-import-an-sql-file-to-mysqldump-using-command-line